# Planewidth after bending (using pv3d, as3dmod)

Tags: width, papervision3d, plane, vertices

I got a huge problem. I'm stuck there for two weeks now.
It's seems pretty simple.

I'm creating a plane, mapping a texture to it. 
After that I bend it, using the bend modifier from as3dmod.

Of course the plane got smaller after the bending process.

I've tried to calculate the first and last vertices.

```
var sizeAfterBending:Number = (-1 * plane.geometry.vertices[0].x) + (plane.geometry.vertices[plane.geometry.vertices.length-1].x);
```

I calculate -1 cause the first vertex is always negative.

The result of that is, if the plane is 400*533 it working fine.
But with a plane of let's say 640*480 it's not.

I'm missing something. It's really driving me crazy.

Does anybody has any idea?

Thanks in advance.

Cheers, MisterDan

Answer (score 1):

JFY, I solved it.

I was trying to access this information before the rendering was finish.

Of course that's not gonna work ;)

Cheers, MisterDan